# HBase and Phoenix: the data queried for the first time is very slow

Tags: hbase, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight, apache-phoenix

We have some readings in a table (20M reads) with 12 columns (most of them numbers, so it is not very big). The table is created with phoenix and its key is serialnumber+timestamp. The table is compressed ('GZ'). It has a salt of 4.

The HBase cluster is in Azure and it has 4 region nodes.

The issue is that we have noticed that it takes a lot of time to load the reads for the first time (between half an hour and an hour). In the following queries it flies showing really good performance. The table seems to be stuck until it loads into memory.

Any ideas?

Thanks